# Vim completion based on language

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugins, gvimrc

Right now if I hit ctrl + n it will complete words that are in the current document. I've also found a way to define a dictionary. I'm just unsure how to get vim to complete based on keywords in a language.

I don't mind building my own dictionaries. Is there a way to define a dictionary for each language?

Comment: See this answer on StackOverflow:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634114/vim-load-buffer-depending-on-file-type/21634935#21634935.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim comes with the *syntaxcomplete* plugin that extracts the language keywords from the syntax plugins used for syntax highlighting. You can install this as the *omni completion* function via

```
setlocal omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
```

and then trigger via `<C-x><C-o>`. See `:help ft-syntax-omni` for details and how to configure it.

#### Alternative

If you rather want to maintain the word list yourself, define a Dictionary file via

```
:set dictionary=/path/to/dict-file
```

and trigger via `<C-x><C-k>`.